# javascript regex window params

Tags: regex

need help with regex

```
var s = "left=123,top=345,width=123, height= 34, center=yes, help=no,resizable=yes, status=now";
```

need to get all params (name -> value)

tried this way `/(\w+)\s?=(\S+)[\s|,]/`

result:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    string(28) "left=123,top=345,width=123, "
    [1] =>
    string(12) "center=yes, "
    [2] =>
    string(23) "help=no,resizable=yes, "
  }
  [1] =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    string(4) "left"
    [1] =>
    string(6) "center"
    [2] =>
    string(4) "help"
  }
  [2] =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    string(22) "123,top=345,width=123,"
    [1] =>
    string(4) "yes,"
    [2] =>
    string(17) "no,resizable=yes,"
  }
}
```

Comment: ``(\S+)`` matches possibly too much characters. Try the nongreedy version ``(\S+?)``

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use the split method, but don't know if it's good. Comments are welcome.

```
var s = "left=123,top=345,width=123, height= 34, center=yes, help=no,resizable=yes, status=now";
var params = s.replace(/\s*,\s*/g,',').replace(/\s*=\s*/g,'=').split(',');

var arg_array = {};

for(var n = 0, len=params.length; n < len; n++) {
    var arg = params[n].split("=");
    arg_array[arg[0]] = arg[1];
}
```

Result (arg_array):

```
({left:"123", top:"345", width:"123", height:"34", center:"yes", help:"no", resizable:"yes", status:"now"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/(\w+)\s*=\s*([^,\s]*)/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
([\w\d]+)\s*=\s*([\w\d]+)
```

I'm assuming that both parameter and value may contain only letters and digits. You may choose to be more permissive by writing this:

```
([^=\s,]+)\s*=\s*([^=\s,]+)
```